# iOS Fetch/Background Update minimal time

Tags: ios, iphone

Are there any metrics on the background fetch cycle for iPhones available? I'm currently setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval and I'm getting no background fetches unless I simulate it in the debug options in Xcode.

Are there any other ways of communicating updates from iOS phones on a 5 minute interval without having the app open/in the foreground?
This for an app distributed for internal use only in the offices.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very descriptive. Still let's start from few possibilities and then you can elaborate accordingly.First one is - I hope u have turned on "Background Fetch" capability in "Capabilities section.

[image]

Comment: Yes that's enabled. I guess there are a couple of questions - firstly, is there any time interval that is typical for background fetches for a locked iPhone? I.e. should it background refresh every 15 minutes, or 1 hour? I can only see that iOS decides when to run the background fetches, nothing more specific than that.

Comment: iOS takes care of not to poke the your app for the background fetch activity for more than time interval that has been provided. When you set UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum, the app is woken by iOS as frequently as possible. I suggest experiment by passing NSTimeInterval with some constant value rather than using UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum.